# Persistent xinput settings on 16.04 with Compiz

Tags: mouse, compiz, button

I've tried several different methods to make a permanent change to my mouse button configuration to disable the wheel button (xinput set-button-map 10 1 0 3 from the command line - which works but doesn't last). However, whichever method I try (found many different by searching), it does not even survive locking the screen, let alone logging off and on again, suspending or rebooting.

Does anyone have a definitive method that is proven to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not "proven to work", but ...

If you place a `.desktop` file in `$HOME/.config/autostart`, it will be invoked at GUI startup.

You can find `.desktop` files to learn from via `locate .desktop`, or see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure that a screen lock/unlock or a suspend/resume does a GUI startup, but I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to see how to intervene in Hibernate/Wake or Suspend/Resume.